# Which Binary Search algorithm is better in terms of Run Time and Memory?

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-search

I have two version of a binary functions named binary_search_v1 and binary_search_v2. I need to know which one is better than other in terms of space and time complexity and why ? Not able to figure out which one to use ?

To me both looks equal in terms of time complexity. Since the main implementation is binary search.

```
def binary_search_v1(abc,val):
    low=0
    high=len(abc)
    if len(abc)==1 and abc[low] != val:
        return False
    else :
        mid = (low + high)//2
        if abc[mid] == val:
            return True
        elif abc[mid] < val :
            return binary_search_v1(abc[mid+1:high],val)
        else :
            return binary_search_v1(abc[0:mid],val)


def binary_search_v2(data, target, low, high):
    """Return True if target is found in indicated portion of a Python list.

    The search only considers the portion from data[low] to data[high] inclusive.
    """
    if low > high:
        return False # interval is empty; no match
    else:
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        if target == data[mid]: # found a match
            return True
        elif target < data[mid]:
            # recur on the portion left of the middle
            return binary_search_v2(data, target, low, mid - 1)
        else:
            # recur on the portion right of the middle
            return binary_search_v2(data, target, mid + 1, high)
```

In terms of memory the binary_search_v1 is very well than binary_search_v2.

Answer (score 0):

The first function slices the lists in order to recurse on one half or the other. That slicing operation requires copying a bunch of references into a new list, so it will take more time and memory than the other version, which just passes indexes to describe the part of the original list to be searched.

I think the first function is O(N) in space and time, while the more efficient second function is O(log N).